# Draw Flat surface between two tube geometry using three.js

Tags: three.js

I have two TubeBufferGeometry created using `THREE.CatmullRomCurve3()` points. 
What i am trying to do is fill area between those two tubes.

```
var closedSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
new THREE.Vector3( -60, -100,  0 ),
new THREE.Vector3( -60,   20,  0 ),
new THREE.Vector3( -60,  120,  0 ),
new THREE.Vector3(  60,   120, 0 ),
new THREE.Vector3(  60, -100, 0 )] );
closedSpline.curveType = 'catmullrom';
closedSpline.closed = true;

var closedSpline1 = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
new THREE.Vector3(-50, -90,  0),
new THREE.Vector3(-50, 10,  0 ),
new THREE.Vector3(-50, 110,  0 ),
new THREE.Vector3(50, 110, 0 ),
new THREE.Vector3(50, -90, 0 )
] );
closedSpline1.curveType = 'catmullrom';
closedSpline1.closed = true;

var tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry( closedSpline, 100, 1,5, true 
);

var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xb00000, wireframe: 
false } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( tubeGeometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );

var tubeGeometry1 = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry( closedSpline1, 100, 1,5, 
true );

var material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xb00000, wireframe: 
false } );
var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( tubeGeometry1, material1 );
scene.add( mesh1 );
```

Above is code to create two tube geometry. 
Can anyone guide me to right direction or any related example to fill area between two tubes. Thanks

[image]
in this image two red tubes i have working. i am looking for a way to draw flat yellow area between those two tubes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option, you can use `THREE.Shape()` with a hole:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 300);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
light.position.setScalar(100);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

var closedSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
  new THREE.Vector3(-60, -100, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(-60, 20, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(-60, 120, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(60, 120, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(60, -100, 0)
]);
closedSpline.curveType = 'catmullrom';
closedSpline.closed = true;

var closedSpline1 = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
  new THREE.Vector3(-50, -90, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(-50, 10, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(-50, 110, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(50, 110, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(50, -90, 0)
]);
closedSpline1.curveType = 'catmullrom';
closedSpline1.closed = true;

var tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(closedSpline, 100, 1, 5, true);

var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xb00000,
  wireframe: false
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

var tubeGeometry1 = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(closedSpline1, 100, 1, 5,
  true);

var material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xb00000,
  wireframe: false
});
var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry1, material1);
scene.add(mesh1);

// magic starts here
var shape = new THREE.Shape(closedSpline.getPoints(100)); // make a shape
shape.holes.push(new THREE.Path(closedSpline1.getPoints(100))); // add a hole
var shapeGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape); // create a geometry
var track = new THREE.Mesh(shapeGeometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: "yellow",
  wireframe: false
})); // create a track from the geometry
scene.add(track);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, really magical. Thank you. Can you Explain a bit what is getpoints(100) means?

Comment: @GAURANGKORANT You're welcome :) `.getPoints()` returns (the amount of division you've set + 1) points along a curve. Read about it [here](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/extras/core/Curve.getPoints).

Comment: Thanks. Above solution is not working as expected when i change closedSpline, closedSpline1, z axis values to other than 0. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @GAURANGKORANT Yes, I have :) Take a look at this [forum thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/2d-object-in-3d-space-by-vertices/2795) and this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272399/three-js-2d-object-in-3d-space-by-vertices/50274103#50274103).

Comment: i have tried your answer from above comment link. still same result. i have modified points in above answer. if you can see whats issue.

Comment: @GAURANGKORANT Why did you change the current question instead of making a new one? Since you've changed it, it has different meaning and my answer is irrelevant. Don't change answered questions and, moreover, answers!

Comment: ok.I am not much used to this. i just rollback my changes to question. Let me know if i need to change anything else. I think shape is only use x,y points so its always flat surface. Even if i applyQuaternion(), its same result.

Comment: @GAURANGKORANT Yes, correct. But if you create a new question, I'll try to answer it.

Comment: ok. i just created new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350568/how-to-draw-shape-geometry-with-3d-pointsx-y-z-using-threejs-which-is-not-flat.