# threejs creating a polyline offset

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a Geometry with vertices which is a polyline. But the offset I create is not correct. What I'm currently doing is computing the center of the geometry. And offsetting a value relative to the center. Which is not a correct offset.

My current code:

```
    var size = 10;
    var geo = this.mesh.geometry,
        center = new THREE.Vector3();

    geo.computeBoundingBox();
    geo.boundingBox.getCenter(center);

    geo.vertices.forEach(function(vertice){
        var C = new THREE.Vector3()
        C.subVectors( vertice, center ).multiplyScalar( 1 + ( size / C.length() ) ).add( center );
        vertice.copy(C);
    });

    geo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

So now I have another solution in mind, using the previous and next vertice to calculate a better offset base point. The image below might clarify what I'm trying to achieve. I know vertice a, b and c. But what I don't know is the vertice on the collission of the 2 lines with a 90 deg angle.

This way I calculate a better offset per vertice with a better distancing option. Any way on calculating the purple dot between a and b?

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I do need the 90 degree angle. b could be lower and then missing the 90 deg angle.

Comment: Not sure if I got you correctly, but maybe that [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/offsetcontour-function/3185?u=prisoner849) will help.

Comment: Thank you @prisoner849 you helped me out again. This looks really promising. This works for 2D and now I need to find out if I can convert it to a 3D environment.

Comment: Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50274103/4045502) then :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the situation correctly, you should be able to compute the "purpel vertex" (ie center) using the following code. Note that vertex A, B, C are aquired directly, however you may need to modify that depending on how the vertices are stored:

```
  var size = 10;
  var geo = this.mesh.geometry,
      center = new THREE.Vector3();

  geo.computeBoundingBox();
  geo.boundingBox.getCenter(center);

  // Aquire the vertices A, B, C between which the purpel vertex will "project
  // to"
  var A = geo.vertices[0]
  var B = geo.vertices[1]
  var C = geo.vertices[2]

  // Compute vectors between A, B, and C that will be needed to calculate 
  // purpel vertex. Note that "dirAB" is a unit vector (normalized) which 
  // means we use it to find "center"
  const dirAB = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(B, A).normalize()
  const vecAC = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(C, A)

  // This is the distance along AB that the purpel vertex sits at
  const proj = dirAB.dot(vecAC)

  // Compute the position of "center" (the purpel vertex) based on "proj" 
  // distance along the "dirAB" unit vector
  center = new THREE.Vector3()
    .copy(A)
    .addScaledVector(dirAB, proj)

  // geo.vertices.forEach(function(vertice){
  //     var C = new THREE.Vector3()
  //     C.subVectors( vertice, center )
  //     .multiplyScalar( 1 + ( size / C.length() ) ).add( center );
  //     vertice.copy(C);
  // });

  geo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```