# How to convert a shape of a face of a 3D model in three.js into a 2D SVG?

Tags: svg, three.js, 3d, collada

is it possible to generate an SVG with the shape for a particular face of a model in three.js? We are developing an interactive editor for 3D models where you can draw on each wall and we're stuck with this problem.

For example, for this face:
[image]

We want to have an SVG like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few versions of this question out there between programming and math Exchanges. I was able to combine several answers and translate to Three.js' [Vector3](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Vector3.js) and [Quaternion](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Quaternion.js) classes.

Let's say you want to render the first face of this [tetrahedron OBJ](https://polyhedra.tessera.li/tetrahedron/info):

```js
const points3D = [
  Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 1.732051),
  Vector3(1.632993, 0.0, -0.5773503),
  Vector3(-0.8164966, 1.414214, -0.5773503),
];

function pointsInPlaneToPoints2D (points3D) {
  // The normal is a unit vector that sticks out from face.
  // We're using the first 3 points, assuming that there
  // are at least 3, and they are not co-linear.
  const [p0, p1, p2] = points3D;
  const planeNormal =
    (new Vector3()).crossVectors(
      (new Vector3()).subVectors(p0, p1),
      (new Vector3()).subVectors(p1, p2)
    ).normalize();
  
  // Unit vector on the Z axis, where we want to rotate our face
  const zUnit = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
  
  // Quaternion representing the rotation of the face plane to Z
  const qRot = (new Quaternion()).setFromUnitVectors(planeNormal, zUnit);
  
  // Rotate each point, assuming that they are all co-planar
  // with the first 3.
  return points3D.map(function (p) {
    const pRot = p.clone().applyQuaternion(qRot);
    // Output format [x, y] (ignoring z)
    return [pRot.x, pRot.y];
  });
}

const points2D = points3DInPlaneToPoints2D(points3D);
// Draw those with your 2D drawing context of choice
```

Here are the faces of a [truncated icosahedron](https://polyhedra.tessera.li/truncated-icosahedron/info), flattened with this function, and rendered with SVG:

[image: faces flattened from truncated icosahedron]

Comment: This answer is a little simpler, also using `THREE.Triangle`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50274103/592125